# jquery trigger event after adding a class is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my situation, on click of a button, one event is happening, and a class is being add to that element.

I then add another function which take in count this element with that class added.

However it is not working, like if it was not taking in count that class added in the previous function.

Here is my code below:

```js
$(document).on('click', "ul.nav-responsive li:last-child", function() {
  var width_canvas = $('.top-bar-right ul li.medium-3.small-4').outerWidth();
  console.log(width_canvas)
  var dwidth = $(window).width() - width_canvas;
  $('.off-canvas-content').addClass('active');
  $('.position-right').css('width', dwidth);
  $('.off-canvas-content').css('transform', 'translatex(-' + dwidth + 'px)');
});


$(document).on('click', ".off-canvas-content.active", function() {
  alert('test')

  var width_canvas = $('.top-bar-right ul li.medium-3.small-4').outerWidth();
  console.log(width_canvas)
  var dwidth = $(window).width() - width_canvas;

  $('.off-canvas-content.is-open-right').css('transform', 'translatex(0px)');
});
```

so on the first function i add an active class to the .off-canvas-content
on the second function id like when off-canvas-content has the active class, to trigger an alert.

Is it not working.

Comment: does it work with 2 consecutive clicks? It probably can't run in a single click as it is, because when first click is done, there is still no `active` class to find.

Comment: Can you share fiddle/codepen for the same?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and include the HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

Nest the second function within the first function since the second function depends on the completion of the first function. When separate, they are evaluated as individual functions so at that time `.content.active` doesn't exist yet.

### Demo

```js
$("ul.nav li:last-child").on('click', function() {
  $('.content').addClass('active');
  $(".content.active").on('click', function() {
    $(this).text('WorX!');
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 30%;
  color: white
}

.content.active {
  background: blue;
  transform: scale(5);
  font-size: 18px;
  color: gold;
  margin-top:20%
}

li {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<ul class='nav'>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<div class='content'>Content</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```